# React. Transferring data from textarea to array JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, textarea

I just started working with React and JSON and require some help. There is a `textarea` field in which a user enters some data. How to read row-wise the entered text as an array into a JSON variable of the request? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The result I want is

> ````
>      {
>         id: 3,
>         name: 'Monika',
>         birthDay: '1999/01/01',
>         countryDTO: 'USA',
>         films: [
>                   'Leon:The Professional',
>                   'Star wars',
>                   'Django Unchained',
>                ],
>     } ```
> ````

My code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Form, FormGroup, Label } from 'reactstrap';
    import '../app.css';

    export class EditActor extends React.Component {
    state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        birthDay: '',
        countryDTO: '',
        films: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.actor) {
            const { name, birthDay, countryDTO, films } = this.props.actor
            this.setState({ name, birthDay, countryDTO, films });
        }
    }

    submitNew = e => {
        alert("Actor added"),
            e.preventDefault();
        fetch('api/Actors', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                birthDay: this.state.birthDay,
                countryDTO: {
                    title: this.state.countryDTO
                },
                films: [{ title: this.state.films }]
            })
        })
            .then(() => {
                this.props.toggle();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        this.setState({
            id: '',
            name: '',
            birthDay: '',
            countryDTO: '',
            films: ''
        });
    }

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">   
                            <h3> <b>Add actor</b></h3>

                    <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="id">Id:  </Label>
                                <input type="text" name="id" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.id} /><p />

                    <Label for="name">Name:</Label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.name} /><p />

                    <Label for="birthDay">Birth day:</Label>
                    <input type="text" name="birthDay" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.birthDay} placeholder="1990/12/31" /><p />

                    <Label for="country">Country:</Label>
                                <input type="text" name="countryDTO" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.countryDTO} /><p />

                    <Label for="Films">Films:</Label>
                    <textarea name="films" value={this.state.films} onChange={this.onChange} /><p />
                    </FormGroup>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                <Form onSubmit={this.submitNew}>
                            <button class="editButtn">Enter</button>
                </Form>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
            </table >
        </div>;
    }
}

export default EditActor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the below code it will work automatically.

**State declaration**

```
 this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      films:["Palash","Kanti"]
    };
```

**Change in onechange function**

```
onChange = e => {
  console.log("values: ", e.target.value)
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.split(",") })
}
```

change in textarea

```
  <textarea name="films" value={this.state.films.map(r=>r).join(",")} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Code is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3hrkme

Comment: TypeError: this.state.films.map is not a function

Comment: Declare the films state as array. code like

 this.state = {
      films:["Palash","Kanti"]
    };

Answer (score 1):

You have to close **textarea tag**  and the following code is :

```
<textarea name="films" value={this.state.films} onChange={this.onChange} >{this.state.films}</textarea>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. But it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your problem is that you would like to have each line in the text area dynamically added as an entry in the films array. This can be achieved as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class textAreaRowsInState extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTextareaValue: "",
      films: []
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { films } = this.state;
    const text = e.target.value;
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      // Get last line of textarea and push into films array
      const lastEl = text.split("\n").slice(-1)[0];
      films.push(lastEl);
      this.setState({ films });
    } else {
      this.setState({ currentTextareaValue: text });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { currentTextareaValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <textarea
        defaultValue={currentTextareaValue}
        onKeyPress={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this method is not perfect. For example, it will fail if you add a new line anywhere other than at the end of the textarea. You can view this solution in action here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cdn-135du?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

change textarea() tag 
to

```
<textarea name="films" value={this.state.films} onChange={this.onChange} >{this.state.films}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` :

```
films: {this.state.films.split(",")}
```